# Optimal lookup table query for multiple products?

Tags: mysql

If I have a lookup table with fields like so:

id, color_id, size_id, price

I can easily get all the sizes/prices available for a specific color using:

```
SELECT size_id, price from TABLE where color_id = 2
```

But, if I want to show a price table like so:

```
    red     blue    green   yellow

xs  1.20    1.20    1.29    1.39
sm  1.40    1.40    1.49    1.59
md  1.40    1.40    1.19    1.59
lg  1.55    1.55    1.80    1.94
xl  1.55    1.55    1.80    1.99
xx  2.01    2.05    2.40    2.68
```

Is there a way to do so w/o doing a query for each color? Or is there a better way to structure the data?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The query you have should work if you don't include a WHERE clause. Without a WHERE clause all values are returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select size_id, sum(if(color_id=1,price,0)) c1, sum(if(color_id=2,price,0)) c2, sum(if(color_id=3,price,0)) c3, sum(if(color_id=4,price,0)) c4 from TABLE group by size_id
```

At least this works nicely if you do not have a variable number of colors.

Comment: Removing the where clause prevents the need for this.

Comment: Thanks! That could work great. I tried many a futile things, but didnt even know a sum/if could be done that way. As for the variable number of colors, I can just query a COUNT on the active colors list and generate the SQL on the fly as needed.

Comment: @Shawn: haha...yes...that would normally be true, but CFrei's way puts everything is a nice neat rows (that match the table layout) instead of having to very inefficiently parse through the whole result on the PHP side (with 4X the rows) and assemble the table data by matching all the sizes to the table rows.

Comment: @CFrei: It works great, but if I do have more than four colors and the six sizes, how do I get the query to NOT include them. As it is, the result properly has the pricing for each size that matches the colors 1,2,3 & 4...but it also includes ALL the sizes that dont match with colors 1,2,3 & 4 - and has 0's for the c1,c2,c3,c4 prices. In other words, if size not valid for color 1,2,3 or 4...dont include it.

Comment: modify the query: `...from TABLE where color in (1,2,3,4) group by ...`

Comment: Cha-ching! Again...I dont know why I couldnt figure that out. Thanks much!!